# A delicate measure-theoretic question about Jordan curves and arcs in the plane.

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let E be the Euclidean plane and let M(X) be two-dimensional Lebesgue measure defined for each
Borel subset X of E. Suppose that s is an arc in E and that e is a positive real number. Does
there always exist a bounded connected open subset Z of E such that (!) s is a subset of Z
(2) M(Z)-M(s) is not greater than e (3) Z is the interior of a Jordan curve? It is not hard to
show that such a Z exists if only conditions (1) and (2) are required to be satisfied. But how
does one show that Z can be the interior of a Jordan curve, or even be simply connected? Remember
that s can have an infinity of wiggles and can have positive two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer should be yes.

Consider $E$ to be a subset of the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. The complement $U$ of $s$ is simply-connected, so we can map it conformally to the unit disk (taking $\infty$ to $0$, say).

Take the preimage of a circle of radius $r$, close to $1$, under this conformal map. This gives you a Jordan curve, and the Jordan domain $Z_r$ enclosed by this curve will have area tending to the area of $s$. So for a suitable value of $r$, this domain will have the desired property.

(Am I am missing something?)

Comment: Thanks. I think you may have found the right approach
to proving that the answer is "yes", if in fact it is
"yes".But I do not see how the complement of an arc in
the Euclidean plane can be simply connected.


Comment: I didn't say the complement in the Euclidean plane is simply-connected, I said the complement in the Riemann sphere is simply-connected. 

Indeed, a connected open subset of the sphere is simply-connected if and only if its complement is connected.

(The complement in the Euclidean plane is doubly-connected, and conformally isomorphic to the punctured disk.)

Comment: I'll also mention that the same argument works not just for an arc, but for any compact and connected set that is full (i.e. its complement is connected).

Comment: You are right and I apologize. I forgot that the theorem about simply connected planar sets being homeomorphic defines simple
connectedness in terms of complements taken with respect to the
Riemann sphere-rather than the Euclidean plane.